# Integral $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^z e^{a(y^2 - z^2) - 2M(y - z)}  dy  dz$ not finite

Tags: integration

How to prove the integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^z e^{a(y^2 - z^2) - 2M(y - z)} \; dy \; dz$$

is infinite, where $a$ and $M$ are positive numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for $z\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^ze^{a(y^2-z^2)-2M(y-z)}dy&=\int_0^ze^{a((z-t)^2-z^2)+2Mt}dt\\
&=\int_0^ze^{a(-2zt+t^2)+2Mt}dt\\
&\geq \int_0^ze^{-2azt}dt\\
&=-\frac 1{2az}\left[e^{-2atz}\right]_{t=0}^{t=z}\\
&=\frac{1-e^{-2az^2}}{2az}\\
&\geq \frac{1-e^{-2a}}{2az}\geq 0,
\end{align*}
and $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac 1{z}dz$ is divergent, so we are done.

Comment: The last inequality doesn't hold for all a>0. If we take z=1, 1-e^{-2a}>=e^{-2a} doesn't hold for 0<a<ln2/2. Actually, we can take let it larger than 1/2az. The proof still works. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You are right, I missed a term, now I think it's correct.